# PHP:update a stock with values in the cart

Tags: php, mysql, cart

I am currently  working on an eCommerce website, but i need some advice regarding the stock management.

I want the shopping cart to work as follow:

- CostumerA add a productO to cart with a quantity of '1'.
- CostumerB tries to add the same product to their cart but with no success.
- CostumerA logs out or their session expires.
- CostumerB tries to add productO again and is allowed to do so since the product hasn't been added to CustomerA's cart ...

i came up with 2 solutions but neither is reliable from my point of view:

1. add a field 'champ' to Table product that initially have value of product.quantity but change with cart movements.
2. add table Cart and update it with cart movements.

as u can see both solution require lot of work.Is there a better way to implement my shopping cart.

Comment: You only want one customer to be allowed to purchase one product at a time? That's craziness. If someone figures this out, they can monopolize your store, making it impossible for anyone else to shop.

Comment: I hope what user1559104 is saying, is that if productO were to fall under available inventory when customerA adds it their cart, customerB would be unable to add it. So inventory tracking would work at the cart level, rather than being updated after a successful order.  But I could be completely wrong  :D

Comment: @Matt for example ProductO have quantity=2 . we 3 users: user1 add ProductO to cart first and continue shopping, user2 and user3 add ProductO then make the order. now user1 can't order ProductO even if he was first.

Comment: What happens if User1 never logs out? That item will be stuck in limbo. (I'm just playing devil's advocate here).

Comment: i have session control that auto logs out users after certain time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a better way might be to only update if the user checks out and check stock on the product listing pages.

The downside being the following scenario:

- user A adds an item to their cart
- user B adds the same item to their cart
- user A checks out and the item is now out of stock
- user B checks out, but item is out of stock

You'll need to check stock at every point in this process and inform your users what's going on.

Tying up inventory by having a user placing it in their cart is a bad idea.  If user A adds all of the available stock of one item to their cart, no one else can buy it until they either log out, or you log them out with some sort of timeout.